# How to deal with settings for the view?

Tags: angularjs, routes

In our current system we have views that can be used in multiple places, and depending on the context there are "actions" that user can perform. For example, when adding coverage, user is required to go through the insured edit screen. Same screen is used to just edit insured. So, depending in what context it is used, it shows "Add coverage" button. There are other options and fields that are enabled/disabled. We perform all editing in modals. It is easy to open modal and pass in parameters needed for the view. But, if one also wanted to access the view through a route, how would you deal with view configuration options?